# Django model choices: using first element of tuple

Tags: python, django

I have a model with choices attribute like this:

```
commonness_choices = (
    ("1", "very uncommon"),
    ("2", "uncommon"),
    ("3", "common"),
    ("4", "very common"),
)

class Event(models.Model):
    commonness = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=commonness_choices)
```

When I try to use Event.commonness in views.py, it uses the second element of each choice tuple. For example, if I do this:

```
event = Event.objects.get(pk=1)
event.commonness = "uncommon"
```

event.commonness is set to ("2", "uncommon"). When event.commonness is used, it uses the second element, "uncommon", instead of the first element, "2". Is there a way to select and use the first element of tuple?
I wish to use both the first element and the second element of tuple in different cases.

Comment: Looks like object saved with value 2. If you want to change to to 1 then try this
event.commonness = '1'
event.save()

Comment: I mean in the choice of ("2", "uncommon"), how do I use "2" instead of "uncommon". event.commonness give "uncommon", not "2"

Comment: Please show how you are setting the object in the first place.

Comment: strange, my model returns 2. Looks like problem in saving method

Comment: as a side note: you don't need 30 chars to store one ;)

Comment: I have edited the question to show how I set event.commonness. I wish to use both the first and the second element of tuple choice. When I save it as "2" event.commonness only gives "2" and when I save it as "uncommon", event.commonness only gives "uncommon"

Comment: Erm, your question makes no sense. If you set the data to be "uncommon", then obviously that is what Django will report. The question is, why are you doing that? If you want to use the choices, you should set the value to "2" and then use `event.get_commonness_display()`.

Comment: I changed the code so that event.commonness sets to "2" and used event.get_commonness_display() to view the second element of tuple. And it works as I want it to. Thank you for help!

Comment: @eun9312 write your own answer and mark it as answered please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code so that event.commonness sets to "2" and used event.get_commonness_display() to view the second element of tuple. And it works as I want it to. Thank you for help in comments!

Answer (score 0):

I would setup your choices like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    VERY_UNCOMMON = 0
    UNCOMMON = 1
    COMMON = 2
    VERY_COMMON = 3

    COMMONNESS_CHOICES = (
        (VERY_UNCOMMON, _('Very Uncommon')),
        (UNCOMMON, _('Uncommon')),
        (COMMON, _('Common')),
        (VERY_COMMON, _('Very Common')),
        (CANCELED, _('Canceled')),
    )
    commonness_choices = models.IntegerField(
        choices=COMMONNESS_CHOICES, default=VERY_UNCOMMON)
```

For example, whenever you want to call the number, you can do `Event.VERY_UNCOMMON`. That will return `0` (the first element).

Does that make sense?